# Binary Encode a categorical variable with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe with three types of values a,b and c. I want all the a values to be 1 and b,c to be 0, all of them in one column (this is not one hot encoding). How would I do this? I tried doing a for loop with if/else but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Convert a boolean series to `1` and `0`.  Consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=np.random.choice(list('abc'), size=10)))
print(df)

   A
0  a
1  c
2  c
3  c
4  c
5  b
6  b
7  c
8  a
9  c
```

Then

```
df.assign(B=df.A.eq('a').astype(int))

   A  B
0  a  1
1  c  0
2  c  0
3  c  0
4  c  0
5  b  0
6  b  0
7  c  0
8  a  1
9  c  0
```

Or a little more quickly

```
df.assign(B=(df.A.values == 'a').astype(int))

   A  B
0  a  1
1  c  0
2  c  0
3  c  0
4  c  0
5  b  0
6  b  0
7  c  0
8  a  1
9  c  0
```

---

**Timing**

```
%timeit df.assign(B=df.A.eq('a').astype(int))
1000 loops, best of 3: 550 µs per loop

%timeit df.assign(B=(df.A.values == 'a').astype(int))
1000 loops, best of 3: 306 µs per loop
```